# Transfer of array values between activities

Tags: android

What is the simplest way to transfer (save/load) the values of an **array variable** (i.c. the variable has the form of int [10][100], so 1000 values) between two activities?

Comment: `the simplest way` is opinion-based. How do you know if the way is really simplest?

Answer (score 1):

In your first Activity:

```
int[][] myArray = new int[10][100];

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("myArrayKey", myArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your second Activity:

```
int[][] myArray = (int[][]) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("myArrayKey");
```